# PHP Get specific value from stdclass Object

Tags: php

I have a output like this when I `print_r();`

```
(
    [WebTransactionResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AmountBalance] => 0
            [AmountLoaded] => 0
            [CardNumber] => 60016400000256
            [CardRefNumber] => 
            [CardType] => 
            [Currency] => 
            [CurrentTier] => Silver Loyalty
            [CustomerFirstName] => Member
            [RedeemItem] => 
            [ResponseCode] => 0
            [ResponseMessage] => Success
            [ReversedTransactionIds] => 
            [SequenceCode] => 
            [StoreId] => 1721
            [SuccessTransactionIds] => 
            [TerminalId] => 4377
            [TotalAmountBalance] => 0

        )

)
```

I want to print only the value for `[TotalAmountBalance]` How should I do it? Same way I want to print each values in separately. Please help

Comment: Have given answer to print each values separately

Comment: this is a duplicate of at least a dozen questions. please search before asking. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $objData->WebTransactionResult->TotalAmountBalance;
```

Comment: @Sanjeev welcome :) mark it correct if it helps you :)

Comment: @Sanjeev     Marking the Solution that solved your problem as the correct answer has 2 major benefits.1.) It helps any visitor or SO Member with a similar problem see (at a glance) the answer that solved your Problem. 2.) It is a way of virtually showing appreciation (buying the contributor a beer) for spending time & thoughts on  your problem [which encourages him/her to keep up the good work.]